# Which feature of Facebook Timeline should be used to indicate a publication has released a issue and why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

It seems obvious to me that the weekly pinned post that appears at the top of the page for 7 should be the current issue (But I could be wrong of course...please tell me if I am...)

My goal is to make the back issues of a publication available for sale (on an eCommerce website) when people look at the reverse chronological history of the timeline.

I want the back issues listed in the timeline to be easily distinguishable from the rest of the older content in the timeline.

Should I use Milestones or Starred Posts to accomplish this?

Milestones?

Starred Posts?

I've noticed that on timeline sites for major publications like [NYT](https://www.facebook.com/nytimes) and [WSJ](https://www.facebook.com/wsj) that it is rather difficult to find a date in the timeline when they have released a publication.

Comment: NYT and WSJ publish daily. It makes no sense for them to notify of each issue.

Comment: @dnbrv Can you suggest a publication that does notify on a per issue basis?

Comment: Look at some magazines.

Comment: @dnbrv I'm just looking for a good example that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A milestone would just give it an icon at the top, a featured post will make it full width but in the end I would recommend neither.

There wouldn't be a way to filter efficiently when going back.

Your best bet would be to roll it into a custom open graph application post from there and also have it as a separate tab (e.g. Publications) showing *only* those posts.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, since the idea is to filter out and only display posts that are actual releases of publications.  Do we just have to make a list of which posts they are in relation to an Open Graph application?  Because I am not aware of any way of "tagging" posts so that they can be marked as "a publication release".

Comment: (so I can find them using Open Graph)

Comment: Although it doesn't explicitly say in the documentation you *should* be able to use `GET /<page-id>/{namespace}:{action-type-name}` the same way as `GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches`

Comment: You are basically mimicking Timeline aggregation for the app on a separate tab.

Comment: Where does the new "Publications" tab appear?  

On a user's timeline profile, or on the Facebook Timeline Business page which represents the publication?  

Can you show me a working example of this?

Comment: On your page, your page should be the only one doing actions from that app. The fans of the page should see it on your page as a tab. You could have that as your landing page if you like by changing it in the settings

Comment: @leeand00 I have not seen anyone implement it. In *theory* it should work, you will have to implement your own logic for the timeline menu sidebar to scroll through posts. See your /activitylog to see what I am talking about.

Comment: I just set one up if you want to check it out...(hopefully when you check this my server will be running :/ ...http://www.andrew-leer.com/fbOpenGraphTest.php) it's listed as "Mixup a Smoothie".  Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the functionality.

Comment: Okay so it works when I use my personal user account see: http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a58/Maskkkk/2012-04-17_10-33-40.png but it doesn't work when I am logged in as one of my Facebook Timeline Business Pages; after I c "Use Facebook as:" and select my FB Business Page, all of the facebook widgets on the fbOpenGraphTest.php read "Switch back to Andrew J. Leer to use this social plugin." (http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a58/Maskkkk/2012-04-17_10-38-27.png) that's not what I expected to happen.

Comment: @leeand00 Sorry I took long to reply. You need authentication as a page, currently it seems you only have a user access token so it will redirect you to where you are authenticated. This is a bit far out of the scope of Web Applications and it involves a bit of programming logic and knowledge of Facebook open graph to get to a full out timeline mimic as a tab. For example you can use a fb:activity plugin as a shortcut. If you want to go further discussion, you can find me or other Facebook developers in #facebook irc.freenode

Comment: Well I think I'll take you up on that as I'm a programmer, and I think I'd be able to pick it up.  I'll see you in the IRC!  Thanks! :)